# How to pass GKE credential to kubernetes provider with Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I've created a GKE cluster with Terraform and I also want to manage Kubernetes with Terraform as well. However, I don't know how to pass GKE's credentials to the `kubernetes` provider.

I followed the [example in the `google_client_config` data source documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_client_config.html) and I got

> **data.google_container_cluster.cluster.endpoint** is null

Here is my failed attempt https://github.com/varshard/gke-cluster-terraform/tree/title-terraform

`cluster.tf` is responsible for creating a GKE cluster, which work fine.

`kubernetes.tf` is responsible for managing Kubernetes, which failed to get GKE credential.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the [`google_container_cluster` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/google_container_cluster.html) here at all because the [relevant information](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#endpoint) is also in the [`google_container_cluster` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html) that you are creating in the same context.

Data sources are for accessing data about a resource that is created either entirely outside of Terraform or in a different Terraform context (eg different state file and different directory that is `terraform apply`'d).

I'm not sure how you're in your current state where the data source is selecting an existing container cluster and then you define a resource to create that container cluster using the outputs of the data source but this is way overcomplicated and slightly broken - if you destroyed everything and reapplied it wouldn't work as is.

Instead you should remove the `google_container_cluster` data source and amend your `google_container_cluster` resource to instead be:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  name     = "${var.project}-cluster"
  location = var.region

  # ...
}
```

And then refer to this resource in your `kubernetes` provider:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  load_config_file = false
  host                   = "https://${google_container_cluster.cluster.endpoint}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  token                  = data.google_client_config.current.access_token
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to above question is below:

1. While creating a cluster you need used the kubernetes provider and data source google_client_config

check my code below its working fine for me.

```html
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  project  =   var.project_id
  name     = var.cluster-name
  location = var.region

  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1
}


data "google_client_config" "current" {}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "https://${google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  token                  = data.google_client_config.current.access_token
}
```